# Как сделать чтобы из базы выводилось сообщение с ссылкой с уже подставленным ID?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть системные сообщения!

Иногда в этих сообщениях приходится применять ссылки на разделы системы, система работает, например:

```
сайт.ру/ID/раздел
```

Так вот, в базе сообщений есть поле текст, там есть например ссылка `сайт.ру/<?=$id_cabinet;?>`/раздел естественно она так же выводит в сообщение!

Как сделать чтобы из базы выводилось сообщение с ссылкой с уже подставленным ID?

Система самописная!

**Обновление**

Решил просто добавив в базу несколько полей

1. Вид ссылки (кнопка, ссылка).
2. Сам конец ссылки нужного раздела т.е. /раздел/подраздел.
3. Название ссылки.

Тем самым начало ссылки с id формируется в процессе выборки данных и эти 3 пункта просто подставляются!

Не знаю правильно или нет, но работает!

Answer (score 1):

**НИКАК**

В базе сообщений **не должно быть текстов, содержащих РНР код.** Никогда и ни под каким видом.

Сообщения должны храниться в БД виде **сырых данных.** Отдельно текст, отдельно все другие параметры.

Само сообщение получается динамически, во время вывода. В этот же момент генерируется и ссылка.

Comment: Это я понимаю! Просто пробую! Как сделать есть вариант решения?

Answer (score -2):

PHP код можно хранить в базе и исполнять при помощи EVAL.
Прочитайте по поводу [EVAL ()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php), **но предупреждаю, это может быть опасно, поэтому используйте осторожно**.